2016 Sea Doo RXT 260 Motor Locked Up?
I bought a 2016 Sea Doo RXT 260 that got damaged in a storm. I believe water got in the engine and it sat. There was a bunch of sand and water in the hull.
I took the plugs out, poured ATF down the cylinders and let it sit overnight. New battery fully charged. If I hold down the start button, it very slowly tries to start (very very slowly). ATF comes out of cylinders 1 and 2 slowly, but none out of 3. Any suggestions to get it free?
I took the jet pump off to rule that out.
